# Logcat : Binary XML file line #18 : Error inflating class android.widget.TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I am trying to custom a list view so that when I press enter, new item can automatically be added into list view. This is the first I have done that and got bug. I am not really good at reading LogCat but I predict the problem comes from being incapable of inflating TextView, which I created in my custom list view layout. Please help me find out things go wrong!!! Thank you

Here is my main Activity

```
package com.example.auto_multi_listview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;

public class Auto_Multi extends Activity {

private AutoCompleteTextView auto;
private MultiAutoCompleteTextView multi;
private Button button;
private ListView list_view;
private ArrayList<Content> list;
private MyOwnAdapter listview_adapter;
private String[] hint = {"Aiden", "Aaron", "Adam", "Audrey", "Adrian", "Adriana",
        "Bob","Brooklyn","Barbara", "Nathan", "Natalie", "Noah",
        "Christine", "Caroline", "Cassie", "Henry", "Halley", "Ryan", "Stephanie",
        "Grabriel", "Max", "Paul", "Poppy", "Mathew", "Maria", "Kitty", "Lily",
        "Hannah", "Alice", "Amie", "Tim", "Olivia", "Jenifer", "Jake", "Jack",
        "Emily", "Everlyn", "Susan", "Steuart", "David", "Michael", "Madison",
        "Diana", "Dylan", "Daren", "Sheena", "Yvone"};
private int[] image = {R.drawable.bulbasaur, R.drawable.caterpie, R.drawable.charmander,
        R.drawable.nidoranf, R.drawable.nidoranm, R.drawable.pikachu, R.drawable.sandshrew,
        R.drawable.squirtle, R.drawable.teddiursa, R.drawable.vulpix};

protected void onCreate(Bundle x) {
    super.onCreate(x);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_multi);

    initializeAuto();
    initializeMulti();
    initializeListView();
    initializeButton();
}

private void initializeAuto() {
    auto = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Auto_Multi.this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, hint);
    auto.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void initializeMulti() {
    multi = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Auto_Multi.this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, hint);
    multi.setAdapter(adapter);
    multi.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
}

private void initializeListView() {
    list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    list = new ArrayList<Content>();
    listview_adapter = new MyOwnAdapter(Auto_Multi.this, R.layout.custom_listview, list);
    list_view.setAdapter(listview_adapter);

    list_view.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            final int initial_position = position;

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Auto_Multi.this);

            builder.setTitle("Hold on!!!!");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure that you want to delete this item???");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Definitely", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    list.remove(initial_position);
                    listview_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Oops, nooo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }

            });

            builder.create().show();

            return false;
        }

    });
}

private void initializeButton() {
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Content content = new Content();

            Random random = new Random();
            int index = random.nextInt(image.length);

            content.setImage(image[index]);
            content.setLine1(auto.getText().toString());    
            content.setLine2(multi.getText().toString());

            list.add(content);
            listview_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });
}

 }
```

Here is my MainActivity's layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.auto_multi_listview.Auto_Multi" >

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:hint="@string/hint1" >

    <requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>

<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:hint="@string/hint2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/enter" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1" >
</ListView>
```

Content is the class I created, I don't think it causes bug

Here is my CustomAdapter

```
   package com.example.auto_multi_listview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyOwnAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Content> {

private Activity context;
private int layoutId;
private ArrayList<Content> list;

public MyOwnAdapter(Activity context, int layoutId, ArrayList<Content> list) {
    super(context, layoutId, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutId = layoutId;
    this.list = list;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview, parent, false);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    TextView line1 = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView line2 = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    Content content = list.get(position);

    image.setImageResource(content.getImage());
    line1.setText(content.getLine1()+"");
    line2.setText(content.getLine2()+"");

    return customView;
}
```

}

And its layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.auto_multi_listview.Auto_Multi" >

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_width="50dp"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha"
     android:contentDescription="@string/content" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:textStyle="@string/bold"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
     android:textStyle="@string/bold"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And Log CAt

```
    12-03 07:34:30.228: D/dalvikvm(26650): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 466K, 49% free 3027K/5895K, external 2747K/2773K, paused 33ms
12-03 07:34:39.957: W/KeyCharacterMap(26650): Can't open keycharmap file
12-03 07:34:39.957: W/KeyCharacterMap(26650): Error loading keycharmap file     '/data/usr/keychars/qtouch-obp-ts.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.131072.devname='qtouch-    obp-ts'
12-03 07:34:39.957: W/KeyCharacterMap(26650): Can't open keycharmap file
12-03 07:34:39.957: W/KeyCharacterMap(26650): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/qtouch-obp-ts.kcm.bin'.         hw.keyboards.131072.devname='qtouch-obp-ts'
12-03 07:34:39.957: W/KeyCharacterMap(26650): Can't open keycharmap file
12-03 07:34:39.957: W/KeyCharacterMap(26650): Using default keymap:     /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
12-03 07:34:40.088: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26650): showStatusIcon on     inactive InputConnection
12-03 07:55:25.677: W/Resources(29275): Converting to int:     TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x13c "bold" a=4 r=0x7f0a0015}
12-03 07:55:25.677: D/AndroidRuntime(29275): Shutting down VM
12-03 07:55:25.677: W/dalvikvm(29275): threadid=1: thread exiting with         uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at com.example.auto_multi_listview.MyOwnAdapter.getView(MyOwnAdapter.java:32)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1456)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1288)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1199)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:842)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1862)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    ... 29 more
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'bold' as integer
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:122)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:798)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:446)
12-03 07:55:25.687: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Logcat logs would be appreciated

Comment: Shouldn't you be inflating View in `convertView` rather than using a new `customView`?

Comment: Cause I think the stack trace is my title, already. I will add on now.  As usual, I like to create another customView, partially because I follow the tutorial I learned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
android:textStyle="@string/bold"
```

with:

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

Comment: I actually did that before. However, it notified me an error so I change. I also tried with 1 but same thing happened. Anyway, I think that may be my problem
....
....
Oh, I just do like you said and succeeded, thank you so much. I don't know what happened before.